# Notation of a ring multiplied by polynomial

Tags: ring-theory, notation

What does this notation mean? What do the elements look like?

$\mathbb{F}_p[X]\cdot (X^p-X)$

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret it as any other ring notation of the form $Rx$, that is

$\{p(X)\cdot (X^p-X)\mid p(X)\in \mathbb F_p[X]\}$

The $\cdot$ here may just be there to make the parents vs brackets less confusing.